# How to swap the sides of a left join in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have two tables that I would like to query, tableA has ~53_000 rows while tableB has ~530M rows.

```
SELECT
    b.some_field AS field,
    a.*
FROM tableA a -- 53_462
LEFT JOIN tableB b -- 527_795_032
ON a.user_id = b.user_id
AND a.numeric_field >= b.numeric_field
AND a.numeric_field <= b.other_numeric_field
;
```

This kills the query engine because the right hand side is much bigger than the left, so I think for every row on the left it has to query the right.

In such case (size of right hand side being much bigger than left) what is the best to do:

I am thinking about two possibilities:

- switching up sides and using right join
- creating a potentially much smaller table by querying the rows that exist in the right hand side and join that table

Comment: On traditional database systems, you would look to _index_ this query, which could probably help a lot.  Not sure if Presto would support that.  Note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless; your query should have an `ORDER BY` clause if you intend to use `LIMIT`.

Comment: Btw, `Presto` should have `Full Outer Join`, even though I don't know starting from what version it's supported , seems you will need

Comment: LIMIT is for debug.

Comment: *This kills the query engine because the right hand side is much bigger than the left* ahhh no. The opposite in fact; you *want* the right side to be bigger, because the number of joins is the number of rows in the left side. Please show all relevant indexes on these tables.

Comment: This is a distributed query engine (please check the tags) and there are no indexes involved.

Comment: Please add the query plan to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up creating a temp table that has only the matching rows.

```sql
CREATE TABLE b_temp
....
  IN (
        SELECT
          DISTINCT user_id
        FROM
          a
     )
```

This allows me to filter down b table to a reasonable size.